# Mapping non-compatible properties from DTO to entity

Tags: mapping, entity, domain-driven-design, dto

I'm refactoring a web app to ensure that my entities are always initialized in a valid state. This means that I'm using DTOs for user input, and map those DTOs to my entities after validation.

However, some of the properties of the DTOs are not directly mappable to the properties of the entities. If a DTO contains a base64 encoded image and the entity requires a URL to the image file, I need to save the base64 to a file in the mapper in order to assign the URL of that file to the entity.

It could just be me, but it feels like this kind of stuff doesn't belong inside a DTO to entity mapper. Are there reasons why this might be a bad idea? What strategies are commonly used for this kind of mapping?

Comment: Could you post some example code of how you are doing this today? This will give us a better idea of how to properly advise you.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that in your case you don't have a simple mapping process from **DTO**s to **Entities** because you have application logic in the process. Storing images somewhere and getting an URL/Path for that image is application specific logic, so you probably need a **Service** for it.

Applications usually have some kind of **tasks** or **operations** that it needs to perform and define the **flow** of the application. One way to define this flow is by using **Commands** and attach the **DTO's** to these **Commands**.

For example let's say you have a registration process so the user must enter some data and you need to create an **Account** Entity.

In case of web app, the frontend will have to collect user information and create and send a command to the backend. In this case you will have **RegisterUserCommand**. This command will contain a **UserInfo DTO** property, or will have properties for the user info. For example:

```
RegisterUserCommand {

   string UserName
   string FirstName;
   string LastName;
   Image Avatar;
}
```

The next thing you need is a **RegisterUserCommandService** or (**RegisterUserCommandHandler** depending on your taste and terminology used) that will process/handle the **Command**. You also need a **StorageProvider** that will provider service operations for storing and retrieving images (can be on the File System, Amazon S3, Dropbox etc.) and give you a link. Here is a sample pseudo code

```
RegisterUserCommandService {

  Process(RegisterUserCommand cmd) {

     avatarLink = storageProvider.Store(cmd.Avatar);

     account = new Account(cmd.UserName, ...., avatarLink);

     accountRepository.Save(account);
}
```

If you tell me more about your application I can provider an example for your specific case.

Here are some resources you can check:

- https://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/task-based-ui/
- https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandOrientedInterface.html
- https://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/cqrs-commands-command-handlers-and-command-dispatcher

Comment: I'm actually already using a similar approach to CQRS, but in this particular case, the DTO is used to represent an entity in a form, and also to submit it and apply the changes to the entity. The data for the request and the command are exactly the same; its just that the image needs to be saved/converted.

The primary reason for me asking this question is because I often see people referring to DTO automappers, and I wonder how stuff like images can possibly be automatically mapped. Thats the reason I started thinking maybe stuff like saving images doesn't belong in mappers.

Comment: However, other than that, I see no real reason I couldn't implement the saving of images inside the mapper itself. The mapper could be considered a service itself really.

Comment: I agree that the mapper is a service and you can add saving of images to the mapping process and it's fine to do it :). To me the downside is that this gives the mapper another responsibility: saving images which I think is application specific logic. If you consider the mapper application service then it's OK. If this is in a Service operation then its easier to figure out the flow of the app and more consistent if you have other Services. If it's a small app that is CRUD like it's not a problem :) For larger apps having well defined flow makes makes it easier to implement stuff and debug it.